# Save Session State for web app

Tags: php

I've built a web application and when I enter information, it just disappears when I refresh the page. What script am I looking for and is there any links anyone could provide to help me in the right direction?? Pleaseeeeeeeee

Comment: answer in your question title. (sessions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your data persistent server side. You could use the session by using $_SESSION within PHP or retrieve your data stored persistently in a database.  However that means you will have to make a call to the server, before you refresh your page, by using for example a jQuery ajax call. After saving the data you can refresh your page, retrieve your data and fill in the appropriate information from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [sessions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php):

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data across subsequent accesses. This enables you to build more customized applications and increase the appeal of your web site. All information is in the [Session reference section](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).